# PowerBI show rows without data

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables: Table A and Table B. Table B may reference Table A via its column fkA.

Example dataset:

```
B Table
----------
id  |  fkA
1   |   1
2   |   2

A Table
id
-----------
1
2
3
```

In a table visual i can display a join of B1.id and A1.id and will receive:

```
A.id | B.id
------------
1    |  1
2    |  2
```

The A rows which have no corresponding B are not shown (A with id 3 is not shown)

I have two questions:

1. is it possible to add in those rows of A that have no corresponding B?

```
A.id | B.id
------------
1    |  1
2    |  2
3    |  empty <-- this row should be added
```

2. is it possible to show only those rows of A that have no corresponding B?

```
A.id | B.id
------------
3    |  empty
```

Comment: Try to adjust the relation property with LEFT join (take all row from A and matched row from B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given your data sample:

**Choose Table A and click Merge Queries -> Merge Queries as New**

[image: Merge Queries]

Choose `Join Kind as "Full Outer"` and click on `Table A -> ID; Table B -> fkA`:

[image]

Click on `Expand` and choose Columns that you want to show (keeping prefix or not):

[image]

Lastly, to filter only `empty rows`, click on `B.fkA column filter` and choose only `null` values:
[image]

Click `OK` and you're done:

[image]

Full code here:

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(A, {"ID"}, B, {"fkA"}, "B", JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Expanded B" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "B", {"ID", "fkA"}, {"B.ID", "B.fkA"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded B", each ([B.fkA] = null))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Power Query Editor**, you can try the option **Merge Queries to New** option to create a new table with your required data as shown below-

[image]

When you expand the new table, you will get output as below-

[image]

Advance editor code for the new table-

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(#"Table A", {"id"}, #"Table B", {"id"}, "Table B", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Table B" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Table B", {"id", "fkA"}, {"Table B.id", "Table B.fkA"})
in
    #"Expanded Table B"
```